# How to hide url while displaying image in telegram chatbot

Tags: chatbot, aiml

How to hide url while displaying image in telegram chatbot? I am developing a chatbot using AIML in program-y interpreter which is written in python

This is my aiml code

```
<category>
<pattern>SHOW ME YOUR PICTURE</pattern>
<template>Okay <a href="image url"> </a></template>
</category>
```

It is displaying image along with url here is the image below

[Url displaying along with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3SIx.png)

The url displays even while using `<image>` as well as with `<img src></img>` tag.

I want to display only image whenever user asks. Is there any way to hide image url while displaying images in telegram?

Answer (score 0):

Your interpreter needs to support the rich media elements of AIML 2.1

In this case, the `<image>` tag

```
<category>
  <pattern>SHOW ME DONALD DUCK</pattern>
  <template>
    <image>https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/disney/images/d/db/Donald_Duck_Iconic.png</image>
    Here you are.
  </template>
</category>
```

[image]

Comment: The image tag just works fine for me but it is displaying image with text which is  "to see the image click <urlname>". how do you hide url while displaying image? Do i have to disbale  web_page_preview in program-y? If yes then how?

Comment: What happens if you copy my category and try that? If it still displays the URL, this is a problem with Program Y and you should ask them for support.